# How to get the value in uioutput in ui.R and send it back to server.R?

Tags: r, shiny

In `ui.R`, I put:

```
uiOutput("singlefactor")
```

In `server.R`, I have:

```
  output$singlefactor <- renderUI({
    selectInput("sfactor", "Feature selection:", names(datatable()))
  })
```

Using these, I can show the column names of the data.frame `datatable()` in the select menu. What I want to do next is:

Let's say the column names are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in `datatable()`. I pick a from `ui.R`, then, a is sent back to server so that I can use the subset of `datatable()` that only includes a for the next calculation.

So, my question is: how can I send a back to `server.R`?

Comment: Just create a variable that listens for `input$sfactor`. Something like `my_var <- reactive({if (is.null (input$sfactor)) return(NULL) else return(input$sfactor)})`. Then you can just call that variable anywhere with `my_var()`. Or, just use `input$sfactor`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value will be available like any other input, for example

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("singlefactor")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")

    )
  )
))
,
server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
     output$singlefactor <- renderUI({
    selectInput("sfactor", "Feature selection:", names(mtcars))
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars[,input$sfactor])})

})
))
```

You created a UI element with the name "sfactor" so you can get the value with `input$sfactor`

Comment: Yeah, it totally works! thanks a lot. I am totally new for shiny. So maybe there are a lot of issues that is difficult for me.