# Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable when I use plotly

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on an app in shiny app o rstudio and I have a question in the second Tab of my app

You see the second tab of my app loads a data.frama written in the app.R file and prints it on rhandsome table, this tab has a selectinput that allows me to change between data.frames which is some I was able todo thanks to reactivevalues functions and correspondingly it does the same thing with the plots (which I make with plotly) the problem is that I am trying to make the values change according to the selected data.frame and the selected

I have tried to do it by using the reactive function, like this

```
X.var<-reactive({
    output$varx <- renderUI({
      selectInput("variablex", "Seleccione la variable X", choices=names(TablaD()))
    })
  })
```

and

```
 Y.var<-reactive({
    output$vary <- renderUI({
      selectInput("variabley", "Seleccione la variable y", choices=names(TablaD()))
    })
  })
```

but when I use plotly like this

```
output$plot_three <-renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=I.Plot(), x = ~X.var(), y = ~Y.var(), name = 'High 2014', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            #x = ~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta, y = ~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta
            line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
      
      layout(title = "Grafico Lineal",
             xaxis = list(title = "Valores"),
             yaxis = list (title = "Kwh"))
  })
```

and run the app I get the following error

```
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  104: recurse
  103: FUN
  102: lapply
  101: traceify
  100: plotly_build.plotly
   96: getFromNamespace("prepareWidget", "plotly")
   95: func
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$plot_three
    1: runApp
```

how should I introduce the variables `x = ~X.var()` and `y = ~Y.var()` so plotly can accept them and make the plot

---

Here is the code, like I said before is really long because my app has three tabs my question was in the second tab. Once again thanks for the help and I apologize for the inconveniences. Have a good day

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(devtools)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(excelR)
    library(plotly)
    library(shinyjs)

    ###### Bases de datos para Tab 2

    y<-c("TOTAL","Alberto Lovera","Juan Antonio Rodriguez (Pena Larga)","Masparro","Antonio Jose de Sucre (Macagua)","Francisco de Miranda (Caruachi)",
         "Simon Bolivar (Guri)","Turboven","Guanapa","Leonardo Ruiz Pineda (San Agaton)","Micro Centrales Hidroelectricas","Cuao","Arautameru","Canaima",
         "Kamarata", "Kavanayen","Wonken")
    z<-replicate(17, 0)
    z1<-c(1,5,6,9,8,2,3,4,7,5,2,1,4,6,9,3,7)
    z2<-c(4,4,2,3,5,8,9,5,9,5,6,5,3,6,5,4,8)
    z3<-z1+z2
    #style = list(A1='background-color:orange; color:green;',
    #            B1='background-color:orange; color:green;')

    Lista=data.frame("Plantas"=y ,"Produccion_de_Energia_Electrica_Bruta"=z1,"Consumo_Interno_y_perdidas_en_Generacion"=z2,"Produccion_de_Energia_Neta"=z3)


    ##################

    a=c(1,2,3,4)
    b=c(5,6,7,8)
    c=c(sum(a),9,10,11)
    #Lista=data.frame(a=a,"Numero_de_Unidades"=b,c=c)

    ##################


    #Capacidad instalada de generacion de energia electrica mensual por tipo de unidad del SEN. a;o 2015
    T3<-c(replicate(2," "),"Total sistema Electrico Nacional (SEN)","Total Sistema Interconectado Nacional (SIN)","Hidraulica","Termica",
          "Turbo Gas","Turbo Vapor","Ciclo Combinado","Distribuida","Eolico","Plantas Aisladas","Micro Centrales Hidroeletricas","Termica Aislada","Sistema Fotovoltaicos","Sistema para Agua Potable","Sistemas Hibridos")
    T3.1<-c("ENE"," ") ;T3.2<-c("FEB"," ") ;T3.3<-c("MAR"," ");T3.4<-c("ABR"," ");T3.5<-c("MAY"," ")
    T3.6<-c("JUN"," ");T3.7<-c("JUL"," ");T3.8<-c("AGO"," ");T3.9<-c("SEP"," ");T3.10<-c("OCT"," ");T3.11<-c("NOV"," ")
    T3.12<-c("DIC"," "); T3.13<-replicate(15,0)

    Tabla3<-data.frame(" "=T3," "=c(T3.2,T3.13)," "=c(T3.3,T3.13)," "=c(T3.4,T3.13)," "=c(T3.5,T3.13)," "=c(T3.6,T3.13)," "=c(T3.7,T3.13)," "=c(T3.8,T3.13)," "=c(T3.9,T3.13)," "=c(T3.10,T3.13)," "=c(T3.11,T3.13)," "=c(T3.1,T3.13),"CAPACIDAD INSTALADA AL CIERRE DEL A;O"=c(T3.12,T3.13) )

    #Caracteristicas de las plantas termicas de energia electrica segub tipo de unidad. A;o

    T4<-c(" ","Turbo Gas","Alberto Lovera","Alberto Salazar (Anaco)","Guanta","Planta San Diego de Cabrutica",
          "Termoelectrica Felix Garcia Casimiro (San Fernando)","La Cabrera","Turboven","Guanapa","Termobarrancas II","Fuente Cayurima","Planta A SIDOR","Pedro Camejo",
          "Planta Castillito", "Planta del Este","Termocarabobo","Dabajuro"," Genevapca","Josefa Camejo ","Planta Coro ","Punto fijo ","Planta Ezequequiel Zamora","Argimiro Gabaldon","Enelbar","Planta El Vigia","India Urquia (El Sitio)","Guarenas","Jose Maria Espa;a","La Mariposa","La Raisa ","El Furrial","Jusepin","Petromonagas",
          "Petrosinovensa","Santa Barbara (PDVSA)","Luis Caceres de Arismendi","Termoelectrica Antonio Jose de Sucre","Planta Tachira","Monay","Barcazas Josefa Rufina y Margarita","Picure","Antonio Nicolas brice;o","Bajo Grande","Casigua","Guaicaipuro","Rafael Urdaneta","San Lorenzo","San timoteo (PDVSA)","Santa Barbara del Zulia")

    T4.1<-c("TOTAL"," ",replicate(3,"Anzoategui"),"Apure",replicate(2,"Aragua"),replicate(2,"Barinas"),replicate(2,"Bolivar"),replicate(4,"Carabobo"),replicate(5,"Falcon"),"Guarico",replicate(2,"Lara"),"Merida",replicate(5,"Miranda"),replicate(5,"Aragua"),replicate(2,"Nueva Esparta"),"Sucre","Tachira","Trujillo",replicate(2,"Vargas"),replicate(8,"Zulia") )

    Tabla4<-data.frame("Plantas"=T4,"Entidad Federal"=T4.1,"Numero_de_Unidades"=replicate(50,0),"Capacidad Instalada de Generacion de Energia Electrica (MW)"=replicate(50,0) )


    #Caracteristicas de las plantas termicas de energia electrica segub tipo de unidad. A;o (Tabla 2)


    T5<-c("Turbo Vapor ","Complejo Agroindustrial Ezequiel Zamora","Planta Centro","Josefa Joaquina Sanchez","Ramon Laguna","Ciclo combinado",
          "Planta Don Luis Zambrano","Termozulia","Distribuida","Puerto Ayacucho","Aragua de Barcelona,Bare 10,Bovalle,Cantaura, Clarines,El Cuartel,El Rincon,Santa Ana, Pariaguan","Elorza, Guasdalito, La Macanilla, La Y de Cunaviche, Mantecal","Camatagua, Conisa,Palo Negro, San Jacinto","Arismendi, Barranceas de Barinas, Cuidad Bolivia, Libertad, Puerto Nutrias, Sacapo, Varyna ",
          "Caicara del Orinoco, Fuenta Cuayarima, Pijiguaos, Tumeremo", "Guacara","El Baul, Lagunitas","Coro III, Dajarubo, Tucacas","Camaguan","Cano Zancudo, El vigia, Gorsino, Corillo, Yuben, Ortega, Bailadores ","Cantarrana ","Aragua de Maturin, Caicara de Maturin, Caripe, Caripito, Cruz Peraza, Temblador ","Acarigua, Boca de Rio, Canadroma, Los Hernandez, Los Millares, Luisa Caceres, Maparro, Venetur",
          "Proarepa","Carupano, Cumanacoa, Guiria, Tres Picos, Yaguaraparo","Caloncito, El Pinol, La Fria, La Tendida, Urena","La Concepcion, Monay","Cojora, Cuatro Esquinas, San Carlos, Quisira","Termicas Aisladas","Atabapo","Manapiabe ","Maroa","Puerto Ayacucho","Rio Negro",
          "Guadarrama","Coche","Los Roques")
    T5.1<-c(" ","Barinas ","Carabobo","Vargas","Zulia "," ","Merida","Zulia"," ","Amazonas", "Anzoategui","Apure","Aragua","Barinas","Bolivar","Carabobo","Cojedes"," Falcon"," Guarico","Merida","Miranda","Monagas","Nueva Esparta","Portuguesa","Sucre","Tachira","Trujillo","Zulia"," ",replicate(5,"Amazonas"),"Barinas",replicate(2,"Nueva Esparta"))
    Tabla5<-data.frame("Plantas"=T5,"Entidad Federal"=T5.1,"Numero de Unidades"=replicate(37,0),"Capacidad Instalada de Generacion de Energia Electrica (MW)"=replicate(37,0) )

    #Caracteristicas de las Plantas hidraulicas de Generacion de energia Electrica,A;o

    T6<-c(" ","Hidraulicas","Jose Antonio Rodriguez (Pena Larga)","Masparro","Antonio Jose se Sucre (Macagua)","Francisco de Miranda (Caruachi)","Simon Bolivar (Guri)","Fabricio Ojeda (La Vueltosa)","Jose Antonio Paez (Planta Paez)",
          "Leonardo Ruiz Pineda (San Agaton)"," Micro Centrales Hidroelectricas","Cuao","Arautameru","Canaima","Kamatara","Kavanayen","Wonken")
    T6.1<-c("TOTAL"," ",replicate(2,"Barinas"),replicate(3,"Bolivar"),replicate(2,"Merida"),"Tachira"," ","Amazonas (Rio Cuao)","Bolivar (Salto Arauta)","Bolivar (Salto Hacha)","Bolivar (Quebrada Tapere)","Bolivar (Rio Apacairao)","Bolivar (Rio Macarupey)")
    Tabla6<-data.frame("Plantas"=T6,"Entidad Federal"=T6.1,"Numero de Unidades"=replicate(17,0),"Capacidad Instalada de Generacion de Energia Electrica (MW)"=replicate(17,0) )

    #Caracteristicas de los sistemas de fuente alternas de Generacion de energia Electrica Segun tipo,A;o (Tabla I-C.5.)




    ############## Final de bases de datos para Tab 2

    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      dashboardPage(title = "App ", skin="purple",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Filter App"),
                    
                    #Tabla lateral
                    dashboardSidebar(title="Filtracion de Data",width = 300,
                                     #Primera pestaa          
                                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1",
                                                      
                                                      sidebarMenu(  
                                                        
                                                        # fontawesome class examples
                                                        # https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/
                                                        # https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#additional-styling
                                                        
                                                        # fontawesome site
                                                        # https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/
                                                        
                                                        # glyphicon site
                                                        # https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/
                                                        
                                                        # fa-spin class to get any icon to rotate, and use fa-pulse to have it rotate with 8 steps
                                                        
                                                        # just use the icon name without the fa suffix
                                                        
                                                        # add tachometer icon from fontawesome library
                                                        
                                                        fileInput("file","Ingrese el Archivo en formato csv",accept = c("csv",".csv")), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option
                                                        helpText("Capacidad Maxima: 5 MB",align="center"),
                                                        tags$hr(),
                                                        h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                        checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Cabecera', value = TRUE),
                                                        
                                                        checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "Caracteres como factores", value = TRUE), #Permite al usuario  realizar filtracion multiple
                                                        br(),
                                                        radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator',
                                                                     choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), selected = ','),
                                                        tags$hr(),
                                                        radioButtons("choice","Elija una opcion", choices=c("Data" =1,"Estructura" = 2,"Resumen" = 3 )),
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        tags$hr(),
                                                        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Descargar'),
                                                        br(),
                                                        tags$hr()
                                                        
                                                      )                  
                             ),
                                     #Segunda pestaa
                                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==2",
                                                      
                                                      tags$hr(),
                                                      selectInput(inputId = "S.Table", label = "Seleccione la tabla a editar",choices = c("II-D.16.","II-D.17.","II-D.18."),selected ="II-D.16."  ),
                                                      tags$hr(),
                                                      radioButtons("choice2","Elija una opcion", choices=c("Histograma" =1,"Grafico circular" = 2,"Grafico" = 3 )),
                                                      tags$hr(),
                                                      downloadButton("downloadData2", "Descargar tabla en excel (.csv)"),
                                                      br(),
                                                      tags$hr(),
                                                      br()
                                                      
                                                      
                                     ),
                                     #Tercera pestaa
                                     conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3","contents",
                                                      
                                                      fileInput("file3","Ingrese el Archivo a editar en formato csv",accept = c("csv",".csv"))
                                    
                                     )
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                                  #Cuerpo de la aplicacion
                                  fluidRow( tabsetPanel(
                                    #Primera pestaa.
                                    tabPanel("Hola",value=1,
                                             
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice == 1",
                                                              
                                                              div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',DT::dataTableOutput("dat",width = "100%") ),
                                                              helpText("Numero de fila con observaciones buscadas"),
                                                              verbatimTextOutput("filtered_row")
                                                              
                                             ),conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice ==2",
                                                              h4("Estructura de la data Cargada",align="center"),verbatimTextOutput("Estructura")
                                                              #Imprime La estructura de la data cargada.
                                             ),
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice == 3",
                                                              h4("Resumen",align="center"),verbatimTextOutput("Resumen")
                                                              #Imprime la el resumen de la data cargada
                                             )
                                             
                                    ),
                                    #segunda pestaa.
                                    tabPanel("Segunda pestaa",value=2,"Hola mundo",
                                             
                                             #helpText("editable table"),
                                             
                                             div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',rHandsontableOutput("table")),
                                             br(),br(),
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice2 == 1","Hola",plotlyOutput("plot_one")
                                            
                                             ),
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice2 == 2","Hola 2",plotlyOutput("plot_two")),
                                             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choice2 == 3","Hola 3",
                                                              
                                                              div(style="display:inline-block",uiOutput("varx")),
                                                              div(style="display:inline-block",uiOutput("vary")),
                                                              plotlyOutput("plot_three")
                                                              
                                             )
                                             
                                    ),
                                    tabPanel("Tab 3",value=3,"Hola",
                                    
                                             div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',excelOutput("table_Excel",width = "100%", height = "3000px"))
                                   
                                    ),
                                    id = "tabselected"
                                    
                                  )
                                  )
                                  
                    )
                    
      ))

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      
      ########## TAB 1
      
      data <- reactive({
        file1 <- input$file
        if(is.null(file1)){return()}
        read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
        
      })
      
      ###############Sujeto a cambios########################
      
      # Display data using DT table and using filter option for column filters
      output$dat <- renderDataTable(
        datatable(data(), options = list(lenghtMenu = list(c(7, 15, -1),
                                                           c('5', '15', 'All')), pageLenght = 15), filter ='top',selection = 'multiple', style = 'bootstrap',editable = TRUE)
        #Imprime la data cargada para luego filtrarla
      )
      
      #Imprime la estructura de los datos ingresados
      output$Estructura <- renderPrint({
        str(data())
      })
     
      #Imprime el resumen
      output$Resumen <- renderPrint({
        summary(data())
      })

      #### Uso de las funciones observeEvent y eventReactive para permitir actualizar de la data editada
        #input[["dat_rows_all"]] Filtra la data
      
      ##############################Sujeto A cambios##################################
      
      ############ Download handler for the download button ####################
      # downloadHandler() toma dos argumentos, siendo ambos funciones.

        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste(input$file, ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(data()[input[["dat_rows_all"]], ], file, row.names = FALSE)
          # [input[["dat_rows_all"]] se encarga de guardar el archivo filtrado
        }
      )
      
      #Segunda pestana (Inicio)
      
      ######
      #Guardas los dataframe

      values = reactiveValues()
      values[["II-D.16."]] <- Lista
      values[["II-D.17."]] <- Tabla4
      values[["II-D.18."]] <- Tabla6
      
      
      observe({  
        if (!is.null(input$table)) {  
          temp <- hot_to_r(input$table)
          
          if (isolate(input$S.Table) == "II-D.16.") {      
            values[["II-D.16."]] <- temp
          } else if ( isolate(input$S.Table) == "II-D.17."  ) {
            values[["II-D.17."]] <- temp
          } else if ( isolate(input$S.Table) == "II-D.18."  ) {
            values[["II-D.18."]] <- temp
          }
        }
      })
      
      #Permite cambiar entre tablas
      
      TablaD<- reactive({
        if (input$S.Table == "II-D.16.") {
          TablaD <- values[["II-D.16."]]
        } else if (input$S.Table == "II-D.17."){
          TablaD <- values[["II-D.17."]]
        } else if (input$S.Table == "II-D.18."){
          TablaD <- values[["II-D.18."]]
        }
        TablaD
      })
      
      I.Plot <- reactive({
        if (input$S.Table == "II-D.16.") {
          I.Plot <- values[["II-D.16."]]
        } else if (input$S.Table == "II-D.17."){
          I.Plot <- values[["II-D.17."]]
        } else if (input$S.Table == "II-D.18."){
          I.Plot <- values[["II-D.18."]]
        }
        I.Plot
      })

      output$table <-renderRHandsontable({
        if(is.null( TablaD() )){return()}
        rhandsontable( TablaD() , showToolbar=TRUE , search=TRUE , rowDrag = TRUE,
                       columnDrag = TRUE, rowResize = TRUE, minDimension = c(100, 100))
      })
      
      #####Guardar cambios para Histograma
      # Observa los cambios realizados a las filas para luego actualizar la columna elegida basada en la formula
      
      observeEvent(
        input$table$changes$changes, # observe if any changes to the cells of the rhandontable
        {
          
          xi=input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[1]] # capture the row which is changed
          #datavalues$info <- hot_to_r(input$table) # convert the rhandontable to R data frame object so manupilation / calculations could be done
          values <- hot_to_r(input$table)
          # Calculating the cell value of column C using cell values in column a and b
          # 1 is added to row index because change event row and column indices starts with zero vs R index which starts with 1
          
          #datavalues$info[xi+1,ncol(datavalues$info)] = datavalues$info[xi+1,2] + datavalues$info[xi+1,3]
          values[xi+1,ncol(values)] = values[xi+1,2] + values[xi+1,3]
          #calculate column variable C values based on cell values in column variable a and b
          #Calcula el valor de la ultima columna basado en los valores de las columnas anteriores
        }
      )
      
      
      
      ## plot a histogram using plotly
      ## plotly graph also changes as the table cell values changes
      output$plot_one <- renderPlotly({
        #plot_ly(data=datavalues$info, x=~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta , type="histogram",marker = list(color =c('green','blue','purple','yellow','black','orange','white','brown','pink','red') ) ) %>%
        plot_ly(I.Plot(), x=~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta , type="histogram",marker = list(color =c('green','blue','purple','yellow','black','orange','white','brown','pink','red') ) ) %>%  
          #x=~Numero_de_Unidades
          layout(title="Histograma energia bruta", xaxis=list(title="Valores"),yaxis=list(type='linear'),bargap=0.1)
      })
      
      #Agregar colores
      #marker = list(color =c('green','blue','purple','yellow','black','orange','white','brown','pink','red') )
      
      ####Guardar cambios para Histograma (FIN)
      
      ##### Grafico circular
      #Produccion.de.Energia.Electrica.Bruta
      
      output$plot_two <-renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(
          data=I.Plot(),labels=~Plantas, values=~Consumo_Interno_y_perdidas_en_Generacion , type="pie",
          #labels=~Plantas
          #values=~Numero_de_Unidades
          #values=~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta
          #values,labels="Cosas", values=~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta , type="pie",
          #textposition = 'inside',
          #textinfo = 'label',
          insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          text = ~paste(Consumo_Interno_y_perdidas_en_Generacion , ' Khw'),
          marker = list(colors = colors,
                        line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
          #The 'pull' attribute can also be used to create space between the sectors
          showlegend = TRUE
        ) %>% layout(
          title = 'Grafico Circular',
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
        )
        
      })
      
      ##### Grafico circular (FIN)
      
      ####### Grafico Lineal (INICIO)
      
      # Pulling the list of variable for choice of variable x
      X.var<-reactive({
        
        output$varx <- renderUI({
          selectInput("variablex", "Seleccione la variable X", choices=names(TablaD()))
        })
        
      })

      # Pulling the list of variable for choice of variable y
      Y.var<-reactive({
        
        output$vary <- renderUI({
          selectInput("variabley", "Seleccione la variable y", choices=names(TablaD()))
        })
        
      })

      output$plot_three <-renderPlotly({
        
        plot_ly(data=I.Plot(), x = ~X.var(), y = ~Y.var(), name = 'High 2014', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                #x = ~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta, y = ~Produccion_de_Energia_Neta
                line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 4)) %>%
          
          layout(title = "Grafico Lineal",
                 xaxis = list(title = "Valores"),
                 yaxis = list (title = "Kwh"))
        
      })
      
      
      ###### Grafico Lineal (FIN)
      ############ Download Handler 2 #######################
      # downloadHandler() toma dos argumentos, siendo ambos funciones.
      
      output$down <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste(input$file, ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(data2(), file, row.names = FALSE)
          # [input[["data.frame_rows_all"]] se encarga de guardar el archivo filtrado
        }
      )
      
      
      #Segunda pestana (Final)
      
      #################################
      #################################
      
      #Tercera Pestana (Inicio)
      
      ################################
      ################################
      
      ##### Tab that allows the user to upload and edit an excel file using the excelR
      
      data3 <- reactive({
        file_excel <- input$file3
        if(is.null(file_excel)){return()}
        read.table(file=file_excel$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
        
      })
      
      output$table_Excel <-renderExcel({
        if(is.null( data3() )){return()}
        excelTable( data3() , showToolbar=TRUE, autoColTypes=TRUE,allowComments=TRUE , search=TRUE ,fullscreen = FALSE, rowDrag = TRUE,
                    columnDrag = TRUE, rowResize = TRUE, minDimension = c(100, 100))
      })
      
      #Tercera Pestana (Final)
      
      ###############################
      ###############################
      
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yelling in your title ("PLEASE HELP!!!!") won't get you help as quickly as a properly-formatted, [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48343080/5325862) post

Comment: Maybe  a look to [coolbutuseless](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2019/02/12/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable/) helps. The author says _In general if you get this error it means you’re trying to subset a function (or somehow access an item within a function using $) which (most of the time) doesn’t make much sense in normal R code._

Comment: Hello, first of all i'd like to apologize for yelling (or putting PLEASE HELP ME!!! ) in the title, i did it because i tried anything i could and still didn't get any result (I even check  coolbutuseless page but without success before coming here) and i was geting a little bit desperate, i am including in this comment the code, back then i didnt do it because the code is actually pretty large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to put these newly created inputs in reactive expressions. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459837/how-to-get-the-value-in-uioutput-in-ui-r-and-send-it-back-to-server-r), they behave like "common" inputs. Therefore, this is how you should introduce your inputs in `plot_ly` (here, I used the `mtcars` dataset):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel (
    uiOutput("varx"),
    uiOutput("vary"),
    plotlyOutput("plot_three")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$varx <- renderUI({
    selectInput("variablex", "Seleccione la variable X", choices=names(mtcars), selected = "mpg")
  })

  output$vary <- renderUI({
    selectInput("variabley", "Seleccione la variable y", choices=names(mtcars), selected = "gear")
  })

  output$plot_three <-renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=mtcars, x = ~ mtcars[, input$variablex], y = ~ mtcars[, input$variabley])

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You really should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask a question, so that we can see what your problem is quite quickly.

Comment: Hello Mr.bretauv thanks for your help so far, i tried the example you posted and it has been of great help,but now i would like to ask you something, in my shinyApp work i am trying to allow the user to change between data.frames using a select input  and i also programm it so the plots would change accordingly (The plots beign a Histogram, a Pie chart and a linear plot). As I said before what i want to do is the values introduced in plotly to change  depending of what i choose in in the select input. does it work like this?

Comment: Wel,  that's what the code I provided is supposed to do. Did you try it? I don't understand if you want something different from what this code does

Comment: Yes I did try the example you provided, and then i try the same idea that you showed me but with the x = ~I.Plot()[, input$variablex]  but when i try it like that i obtained a blank plot.

Comment: First of all, you need to get the ```renderUI``` expressions out of reactive expressions. Moreover, when I launch your full app, these ```uiOutput``` are not rendered, meaning that there is a problem either in your ```ui``` or in your ```server```. You should create a small app with your data or a subset of your data, remove all useless components (i.e components which have nothing to do with your problem) and try to see why these ```uiOutput``` are not rendered. When you will have determined this, try to make the plot.

Comment: I took out  the renderUI expressions out of the reactive expressions like you told me and it worked, thanks so much sir. can i ask something else? as you know all my dataframes used in my code are written before it, but do you know a way to have the programm read them from another .R file?

Comment: use the function ```source()``` to run other scripts from the script of your shiny app. You should really use it with the package [here](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) in case you share your scripts with other people